# How can I get hover documentation for string literals matching documented union type members in JS/TS?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a type that includes a union of string literals, each of which have a documentation comment. Now I want it so that when I define a value of that type with a value satisfying that union type, hovering my mouse over the literal value shows the documentation comment for that union member. But that's not happening. Is there a way to make that happen?

For example:

```
type BarArray = (
   /** AAA */
   "a"|
   /** BBB */
   "b"|
   /** CCC */
   "c"
)[]
const barArray: BarArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
// ^ hovering over "a" does not show "AAA"
```

Comment: FYI: this is what a better question looks like (compared to what you had before. please take this as hands-on lesson :) see also [ask] and [mre])